# How can I connect to a Linux hosted database via a Windows Form C# Application?

Tags: c#, php, mysql, linux

Good afternoon,

Sorry for bothering you, but I do have a question regarding a Windows Form C# Application that I need to connect at a Linux hosted database. After managing to finish both the application and the database, I have sent my friend (the one who assigned me the task) the database as a ".sql" file, he imported it on a Linux server (via PHPMyAdmin) and it worked properly, but unfortunately, the C# application does not connect to the database that he "uploaded" on the new server. I do believe that the issue might come from two different situations:

a) The connection must be allowed from the server, using a command such as: "bind-address= x.x.x.x"?

b) The connection string might be wrong? Here is the code for a button that tests if the connection is online:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string MyConnection = "datasource=IP;port=3306;username=username;password=password";
        MySqlConnection MyConn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
        MySqlDataAdapter MyDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        MyDataAdapter.SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * database_name.Users ;", MyConn);
        MySqlCommandBuilder cb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(MyDataAdapter);

        MyConn.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Database connection is established");
        MyConn.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I would have to say that this is the first time I am trying to create such an application, therefore I do apologize if this seems rather a stupid question :( Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue might be that the remote Linux machine might not have port 3306 open.

from the command line you can run :

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --destination-port 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

to open up the mysql port to alow remote connections

the page below illustrates how to do this with various favors of linux.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Regarding port opening, I have used another connection string just now: `string MyConnection = "user id=user;" + "password=pass;" + "server=IP;" + "Trusted_Connection=true;" + "database=DB;" + "connection timeout=30;";` But still, does not work, saying that the "Trusted_Connection" it's an invalid parameter and after trying the same thing via OleDB still not working :(